# log log contourplot

Tags: logarithmic-scale

I want to plot my function on the log-log scale. Why this code doesn't work for me? I write the following one, but nothing happens.

```
ContourPlot[
Sin[3 x]+Cos[3 y]==1/2,
{x,.01 Pi,3 Pi},
{y,.01 Pi,3 Pi},
ScalingFunctions->{"Log","Log"}]
```

Comment: Looks all fine for me when I try it in my copy of version 12. What's the issue?

Comment: Mine is version 11. Can it be a reason for the problem? The problem is that nothing happens. No error is shown. No graph is shown.

Comment: Hm. Maybe if you increase to increase `PlotPoints`...?

Comment: Code works fine with versions 11.2, 113, and 12.0 on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version <=11  try this workaround

```
ContourPlot[Sin[3 Exp[logx]] + Cos[3 Exp[logy]] == 1/2, {logx, Log[.01],Log[3 Pi]}, {logy, Log[0.01], Log[3 Pi]}]
```

[image]